# Why does God not love Satan if He tell us to love our enemies to be as His Children (Luke 6:35-36)?

Tags: nature-of-god, satan, textual-discrepancies, love

If we have to be forgiving and love our enemies to follow The Nature of God The Father and be as His Children, then why doesn't He love His own enemy, Satan?

Matthew 5:44-45 King James Version (KJV)

> But I say unto you, **Love your enemies**, bless them that curse you, **do good to them that hate you**, and pray for them which despitefully use you, and persecute you; **That ye may be the children of your Father which is in heaven**: for he maketh his sun to rise on the evil and on the good, and sendeth rain on the just and on the unjust.

Luke 6:35-36 King James Version (KJV)

> But **love ye your enemies**, and do good, and lend, hoping for nothing again; and **your reward shall be great**, and **ye shall be the children of the Highest**: for **he is kind unto the unthankful and to the evil. Be ye therefore merciful, as your Father also is merciful.**

Comment: What's your source on God not loving Satan?

Comment: "the devil that deceived them was cast into the lake of fire and brimstone, where the beast and the false prophet are, and shall be tormented day and night for ever and ever." - Revelation 20:10. Love is patient and kind (1 Corinthians 13) and God is merciful and kind even to the evil (Luke 6:35-36) but God will cast satan in the eternal fire to suffer forever and ever without any mercy or Love or forgiveness to end it.

Comment: That doesn't prove God doesn't in some way love Satan. Most Christians believe that God will eternally punish some people even though he love them.

Comment: According to scripture, The Love of God involves kindness even to the evil (Luke 6:35) and it involves mercy (Luke 6:36), where is the mercy and kindness of forcing someone to suffer for all eternity? Otherwise that "love" is not based on The Words that Christ spoke in Luke 6:35-36.

Comment: I think God does love Satan.  we are told that God chastens those He loves.  Heb 12:6.

Comment: God is merciful, I believe God has given satan plenty  of mercy and grace.  He freely and continuously roams the earth to devour all of God children that he can.  He continuously tries to thwart Gods plans and take Gods throne.  There is no repentance  or sorrow  from him.  God is just.  We all deserve  Gods wrath, love or not, that includes the devil.  A better question would be:  why would he love and spare any of us?  The devil is hate and all that God is not.  God loves all His creation in some way or another but each has been made for His purpose and His glory, His choice to love or not

Comment: I think we have to put this on you to prove there's a christian group that teaches God *doesn't love* Satan. Once you do that, the frame of the question will be restricted to that group's beliefs. Unfortunately, whether love from God can exist despite eternal torment also given is ... a matter of opinion. (Sorry, I roll my eyes at this point, but it is a very common belief among Christians, so it applies here).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not fully framed. The asker needs to demonstrate that *any* Christian group professes all of the presuppositions. Namely, the asker must show a Christian group teaches that God *does not* love Satan, his enemy.

Comment: Censorship, that's sad. God does not love satan if he will cast him to be tortured in hell for all eternity. There is no mercy or kindness towards him in that. (Kindness and Mercy are a part of Love according to Christian Scriptures as I pointed out earlier). The will to do harm is not Love.

Comment: The will to punish in hell is justice. Since God is love, even his punishment stems from his love. God disciplines his children because he loves them, which can readily produce pain. Hell is not an indication of God's mercy, but giving all those people a lifetime to choose heaven instead is an indication of his mercy. Our own conception of love does not supercede God's conception of it or all of God's other attributes.

Comment: Also, please edit your revelation verse in your question

Comment: @God_Is_Love It's not censorship - it's just ensuring the site sticks to its topic. This site is about the documented beliefs of Christian groups. If you can't demonstrate a Christian group believes this, it's not on-topic here. Please read this Meta discussion: [What is the Biblical basis for Oompa Loompas?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6008/6071)

Comment: @God_Is_Love You might this article helpful: https://www.gotquestions.org/does-God-hate.html

Comment: God is not under any compulsion to obey the commands he gives to mankind. That’s the great thing about being God.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is my short answer. And please bear in mind, that when I (and others) disagree with some of your points, that is not us trying to "censor" you "just because you don't like my question".  People who go to the trouble of giving you an answer do so because they think your question is worth answering.

Jesus plainly gave us the mind of God on the matter of the divine judgement against Satan. Nearly 2,000 years ago Jesus warned piously religious men of his day that they were of their father, the Devil, *because of their disbelief* and hatred of himself.

> ...you are unable to hear what I say. You belong to your father, the devil, and you want to carry out your father's desire. He was a murderer from the beginning, not holding to the truth, for there is no truth in  him. When he lies, he speaks his native language, for he is a liar and the father of lies. Yet because I tell the truth, you do not believe me! - John 8:43-45

We should all know what the Bible says about liars and murderers not getting into God's Kingdom (Revelation 9:21 & 21:8).  There is absolutely nothing in the Bible to indicate that Satan might have repented of his evil.  It shows a progression of wickedness over thousands of years. Those verses (above) teach that some remain set in their evil deeds and they will end up in the sulphuric lake of fire, foremost being Satan:

> And the devil who deceived them, was thrown into the lake of burning sulphur, where the beast and the false prophet had been thrown. They will be tormented day and night for ever and ever. - Revelation 20:10 & 14:9-11

Now, here is the astounding bit. God judges those unrepentant evildoers in that way **because** he is love. This is where God's divine love is infinitely superior to our sloppy, emotional idea of love. The sinful, human idea of love tries to cover things over, to make things better with an idea that more love on our part will change the wicked one.

Well, God's love is melded to his righteousness, and perfect love demands perfect righteousness.  God's love is all-consuming, burning, cleansing love, and that is equally true of his righteousness. Thus, those who wilfully reject God's love will not be cleansed and consumed by it; they will experience the judgement on those who hate God.  They will be consumed by the burning of God's judgement - which is an everlasting burning.

This applies to another realm, another state, so the language of scripture speaks of that which we understand in our physical realm, but this everlasting burning is not like anything we know of here on earth. Yet it is a just judgement because God is love. Perfect love combines with perfect judgement in the final state of the unrepentant wicked.

Just as divine love is a divine burning that sanctifies the saints, that keeps them without spot from this sinful world, that purifies them like refined gold and results in burning worship from cleansed hearts, so divine judgement is a divine burning. It consumes the wicked without destroying them, it keeps them from God's holy heaven and presence, it confirms the wicked as being incorrigibly wicked, and Satan is incorrigibly wicked. Thus, Jesus' pronouncement that people who make their 'father' Satan by disbelieving and hating Christ, will have their portion alongside Satan, when the day of judgement comes.

We may find this hard to accept, but when this comes from the lips of Jesus himself, he whom Satan tried to tempt into sin, to join his unholy ranks, and we realise just who Jesus is - the apple of God's eye - the very representation and being of God - then we accept God's righteous judgement of such unmitigated evil. We believe the scripture that warns us that there is a point at which there is

> ...no sacrifice for sins left, but only a fearful expectation of
>   judgement and of raging fire that will consume the enemies of God.
>   (Hebrews 10:26-27)

Because that judgement comes as a result of having rejected God's love, the burning is awful, not purifying. We have been warned clearly in the scriptures, and from the very lips of Jesus himself.

If you remain unconvinced by this answer, please read what else Jesus said on the matter in Luke 16:19-31.

---

This is a good enough question - good enough to proffer an answer. I disagree with those who wish to "close this question as off-topic because it is not fully framed... the asker must show a Christian group teaches that God does not love Satan." Already two answers have shown individuals representing different Christian groups DO argue that God does not love Satan, and I'm going to be a third such individual, representing yet another Christian group. To close this question down seems like an attempt to stop such answers coming forward. Neither is it significant if any one particular group or another objects to the idea of God loving Satan, for if it can be shown from the Bible that Jesus objects to that idea, then that is all that is needed to answer your question, even if every Christian disagreed with Jesus on that point. "Let God be found true, though every man be found a liar." Romans 3:4

The very 'threat' of closing a question down puts people off answering, for several hours is frequently required to answer questions on here. More than once I have spent some hours crafting an answer only to find the question has been closed by the time I try to post it.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Thank you for taking the time and trouble to consider what you call my 'rant/complaint' about Christianity SE. I have no concern about what you have done because I do not feel strongly about anyone disagreeing with me. I have given my answer and if you continue to disagree strongly enough to move some of my points into 'a note', then I hope that makes you feel very happy.

Comment: I'm cheerfully indifferent, Korvin. I do not care to enter into debates and I know that some people will disagree with me. It's par for the course on here. I have had my say and will leave it at that, thank you.

Comment: I'm very happy to have that section at the end instead of the beginning.

Comment: We have an accord, I'll remove the other comments.

Answer (score 4):

**Why does God not love Satan if He tell us to love our enemies to be as His Children (Luke 6:35-36)?**

The short answer is: **God is love** [(1 John 4:7-21)](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20John%204%3A7-21&version=ESV).

> Beloved, let us love one another, for love is from God, and whoever loves has been born of God and knows God. Anyone who does not love does not know God, because God is love. In this the love of God was made manifest among us, that God sent his only Son into the world, so that we might live through him. In this is love, not that we have loved God but that he loved us and sent his Son to be the propitiation for our sins. 11 Beloved, if God so loved us, we also ought to love one another. No one has ever seen God; if we love one another, God abides in us and his love is perfected in us.
>
> By this we know that we abide in him and he in us, because he has given us of his Spirit. And we have seen and testify that the Father has sent his Son to be the Savior of the world. Whoever confesses that Jesus is the Son of God, God abides in him, and he in God. So we have come to know and to believe the love that God has for us. God is love, and whoever abides in love abides in God, and God abides in him. By this is love perfected with us, so that we may have confidence for the day of judgment, because as he is so also are we in this world. There is no fear in love, but perfect love casts out fear. For fear has to do with punishment, and whoever fears has not been perfected in love. We love because he first loved us. If anyone says, “I love God,” and hates his brother, he is a liar; for he who does not love his brother whom he has seen cannot[a] love God whom he has not seen. And this commandment we have from him: whoever loves God must also love his brother.

However, Satan is sinful and hates all of God's creation including the Creator himself. He is so full of hate that he would not desire to be in heaven with those he has no love for.

> Satan Hates the Holy Spirit. I think this might just be a blind spot in contemporary theology. We know that Satan hates God and marriage and evangelism and even church planting.  But I have never heard anyone reference his hatred for the Holy Spirit.
>
> As I ponder this idea I see more and more evidence to support the statement used as a title for this post. Sure, there is the obvious logical agreement: Satan hates God, the Holy Spirit is God, thus Satan must hate the Holy Spirit. However, affirming the logic of a statement is not the same as pondering the implications. So why does Satan hate the Holy Spirit and how is this seen in everyday life? - [Satan Hates the Holy Spirit](https://www.uniontheology.org/resources/doctrine/god/satan-hates-the-holy-spirit)

God loves Lucifer, but Satan has no love to return to his Creator. Pride fuels Satan's hate and desires not to be with God.

> Pride fuels Satan’s hate The devil made it known he wishes to be exalted during his temptation of Jesus in the desert.
>
> An important clue to Satan’s hatred is contained in the third temptation he makes to Jesus in the desert. Showing Jesus all the kingdoms of the world, he says, “All these I shall give to you, if you will prostrate yourself and worship me” (Mt 4:9).
>
> Here we see the curtain pulled back, and we glimpse for a moment the kind of inner torment that dominates Satan. He cannot bear that he is a creature and that there is another — God — who is to be adored.
>
> Thus, in his colossal pride, he hates, first of all, God. And by extension, he hates everyone and everything that manifests the glory of God. Even more, he hates those who seek to adore God, rather than him. In his venomous pride, he seeks to destroy the Church, which declares the glory of God and reminds us that God alone is to be adored. Surely he hates and seeks to destroy those who even try to adore God.
>
> As the text from the temptation in the desert suggests, Satan is tormented by pride, and his torment is filled with deep hatred for all who worship God and all who draw others to the worship of the one, true God. - [Pride fuels Satan’s hate](https://www.osv.com/OSVNewsweekly/ByIssue/Article/TabId/735/ArtMID/13636/ArticleID/14549/Pride-fuels-Satan%E2%80%99s-hate.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

First, we need to put Jesus’ words into context.

In Matthew 5:38-42 Jesus reminds his audience of the Mosaic Law in Leviticus 19:18 to “love your neighbour as yourself”.  It was the strict Pharisees (of the school of Shammai) who added to this command what they thought it implied – to “hate your enemy”.  Jesus corrected this error by saying “Love your enemies and pray for those who persecute you.”  Jesus was not speaking about Satan.  Jesus was speaking about our relationships with other humans.

Luke’s account of the same event introduces additional insights.  Again, Jesus is speaking about how we relate to our neighbours, other people we come into contact with.  We are to do good to all men,  not just by showing love to those who love us but by “going the extra mile” and helping those who do not love us, to our enemies.  Satan is never mentioned.

Yes, verse 35 says that God is kind to the ungrateful and wicked.  Yes, verse 36 tells us to be merciful, just as God is merciful.

But nowhere does Jesus ever say that we are to love Satan.  Nowhere in the Bible does it say that God loves Satan.  God’s perfect love, mercy and justice came together at Calvary when Christ laid down his life to atone for sin – for the sin of the world – sin that came about when Satan uttered the first lie to Eve that she would not die if she disobeyed her creator.

Regarding God’s mercy, James 2:13 reminds us that “judgment without mercy will be shown to anyone who has not been merciful”.  Has Satan ever shown mercy to anyone?

Repentance precedes forgiveness, and repentance means a change of heart, mind and of deeds.  Has Satan ever repented and sought God’s forgiveness?

Satan is not merely God’s enemy.  Satan is evil and seeks to overthrow God.  Satan is opposed to everything that God represents, namely holiness, love, justice and mercy.

You ask, “where is the mercy and kindness of forcing someone to suffer for all eternity?”  Wrong question.  Ask, instead, where is the justice in allowing sin to go unpunished?  What sort of God would turn a blind eye to sin and pretend it didn’t matter?

Why did God, in Jesus, have to come to earth and die that awful death in order to atone for the sins of the world?  Because God is holy, righteous and just, as well as merciful and loving.

It is presumptuous to try and put God into a box of our own devising.  Who are we to challenge God’s sovereign right to defeat evil and deal with all who disobey him?

You have already quoted Revelation 20:10 (in a comment) which describes the fate that is in store for Satan.  God, who is Alpha and Omega, who knows the beginning from the end, is in full control and His will shall be done in spite of Satan and all who follow him.

Comment: Love does not harm, instead of punishing "sin" actually protecting the victims by stopping the sin would be a more loving method (less suffering).

Comment: Your question and comment  here falls more in line with; "why does God have the right to punish sin?"  It would seem you fall in line with pity and love for satan instead of our Creator.  Your question denies any Christian or  Bibical belief.  Quite frankly, I vote to shut this down as I find it offensive to God with you comments.  It would even seem you pity satan more than mankind as you worry only of torture for the devil instead of your fellow mankind.

Comment: This place is about asking questions, it's sad that you want to censor me just because you don't like my question. What about "do unto others as you would have them do unto you"? By the way, if God can forgive satan, who is seen as the most evil, then of course he can forgive humanity, too. I never said that I wasn't concerned about the belief of humanity being threatened and bullied with eternal torture by a supposedly perfectly good god of forgiveness and mercy.

Answer (score 1):

Jesus also prayed:

> Father, forgive them; for they know not what they do. (Luke 23:34)

**Love your enemy** should be understood in the context that those who persecute us do not fully understand what they are doing. They are doing evil, but do not fully understand the character of the most high, and do not know that they are a slave to Satan in need of saving. Like Saul (Paul), they too have a chance at salvation.

However, those who constantly refuse every ray of light, consistently choose companionship with evil despite evidences of God's love, will have emptied out the cup of mercy. They have hardened their heart to such a state that there is no return.

To Satan, and all those beyond repentance God declares:

> you shall be a horror, and never shall you be anymore. (Ezekiel 28:19).

Answer (score 0):

God's love to all creation is demonstrated in his benevolence and so he expects from us. The message Jesus was passing is that don't let evil run in your heart towards men, for if you allow it, you cannot be a good person - for the negative acts towards the enemy pictures you as a wicked person. But by praying and blessing them, you cultivate a good attitude and character like God. God is the one that can avenge you and justified in doing do because his decisions are made in the light of the future but we are limited in knowledge.

Comment: Thanks for your answer to the question. However, it doesn't really address the question, which is about God loving Satan. Additionally, external references are requested for all sources, and Scripture is always appreciated. See [what makes a good, supported answer](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/692/what-makes-a-good-supported-answer) and explore our [help center](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help). I hope you will stick around and see the other questions and answers on the site.

Answer (score -2):

The simple answer is after the Fall of Adam & Eve when Satan overstep the Permissive Will of God by "touching" Eve, God is the one who made a Holy Decree a "perrenial enmity". God is the one who declares war with Satan and his demons vs. the Woman and Her seeds or offspring.

> "***I will put enmity between you and the woman,
>       and between your seed and her seed;
>   he shall bruise your head,[a]
>       and you shall bruise his heel.”*** (Genesis3:15)

God declared War with Satan and his demons and future human cohorts, so the bible is clear we must not love Satan but we are commanded in union with the Woman to crush his ugly proud head.